# Perl check for input, otherwise use default

Tags: regex, perl

I would like Perl to check the command line to see if there were input files/arguments. Otherwise, use the default file when there are no arguments:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

open(INPUT, "<", "./list2") || die "Couldn't open list for reading: $!\n";

while (<INPUT>)
{
  # print stuff;
}
close(INPUT);
```

I've got the default file (list2) that will be opened, but don't know how to check for input. I'm thinking of using a conditional statement (if *argument_exists* then read the input from the command line; else open the *default_file*). Does this exist in a library in Perl, or is there a regular expression ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parameters to your script are held in `@ARGV`.  Therefore, simply check if that array contains any values, and add your desired logic.

You can also use `@ARGV` for reading from your default file like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

@ARGV = './list2' if ! @ARGV;

while (<>) {
    # print stuff
}
```

Comment: `push @ARGV, './list2' if !@ARGV`?  or `@ARGV = ('./list2') if ! @ARGV;`?  That scalar assignment to an array just looks wrong....

Comment: @tjd Yes, both alternatives are functionally equivalent and are fair choices from a style/readability perspective.  Amusingly, if you Deparse the 2nd option, it will remove the parenthesis.  However, it will also change if ! to unless.

Comment: @Miller Thanks for the help ! Your solution was right to the point of my question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're trying to read the file, it might make sense to check if the command line argument file exists. You can also make sure the argument is a file, not a socket or some other weird thing you're not expecting.

```
my @temp_array = @ARGV;         #make a copy of command line arguments
@ARGV = ();                     #we will re-build this list
foreach (@temp_array) {         #check the validity of every argument
    if (-e and -f) {            #-e means the path exists, -f means it's a file
        push @ARGV, $_;         #add this back to the @ARV list
    } else {
        print "Path '$_' is invalid\n";
    } #/else
} #/foreach

if (!@ARGV) {
    push @ARGV, './list2';
}
```

Comment: Your solution presents an interesting result. If the file doesn't exist, output the invalid filename with Path <filename> is invalid. Otherwise, the file can be further processed.